# Excel - Sum the quantity of unique items in a table

Tags: excel, sum

I have the following format for my data. The bolded items on the left are what I am trying to make, items in column `C` are the materials needed, and column `B` are the quantity of that material. In column `G` I have a unique list of items which I want to correspond to their total quantities in column `F`.

**Techniques I've already tried that didn't work:**

- VLOOKUP
- SUMIF
- SUM
- IF
- COUNTIF
- Pivot Table
- Combination of all of the above.

  I've already stumped two of my Business major friends and I've watched a dozen tutorials which are way simpler than what I'm trying to do here.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to find how many Arcanite Bars you have in B and C, our how many Force Reactive Disks you can male with the quantities in column F? If it is the second, do you want to take into account the other items you want to make?

Comment: Sorry, let me be super clear. In this game, I want to craft all those items, so I am taking note of the total amount of supplies I will need for everything. I want to go and total up the materials I need via column `F` and `G`. `G` would correspond to the material name and `F` corresponds to the total quantity that I will need.

Comment: [Further example](http://i.imgur.com/QOwijkv.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
=SUMIF(C:C;"="&$G2;B:B)
```

[image]

**EDIT** based on Wyatt Shipman comment

```
=SUMIF(C:C;$G2;B:B)
```

Comment: Improperly formatted? I'm not quite sure. See [link here](http://i.imgur.com/jLk4iYX.png)

Comment: That is only checking to see the item exists in the unique list. And you don't need to concatenate the = in the SUMIF

Comment: Works in my excel. Try to play with " or semicolumn. Not sure what excel you have

Comment: @WyattShipman  You are correct about the `=` sign, but **wrong** about the item count.  `B:B` will be the `sum_range`

Comment: @Hatefiend Depending on Regional settings, either comma `,` or  semicolon `;` may be the separator.

Comment: @ron that's not what the op is looking for. I'll post an answer when I get to a computer

Comment: @WyattShipman  I'd be interested in your interpretation of his question, as it seems to me that the SUMIF result is exactly what he wants

Comment: Ah @RonRosenfeld is right. Putting `,` instead of `;` yielded this formula to be formatted correctly, despite Excel telling me there was an error with `C:C`. Anyhow, this [did work for me](http://i.imgur.com/5Hq88eN.png). What is `"="&` and why use that over `EQUALS()`?

Comment: @Hatefiend `EQUALS()` is not a MS Excel function.  And, as has been written in the comments `"="&` is superfluous.  It would resolve to `=G2` which, in the function, is equivalent to merely `G2`.

Comment: I just used example from Microsoft help =SUMIF(A2:A5;">160000";B2:B5) and exchanged > with =...

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sorry -- I'm so used to Java where we have `Object.equals()` (haha). Thanks everyone!

Comment: Sorry. Based on his initial "I have tried SUMIF and it didn't work" and his other comments, I thought he was trying to show which items he could make based on his materials list and thought he would input his quantities into column F for what he had. @RonRosenfeld